# Partial XOR-SAT algorithm + explained?

Tags: algorithm, xor, boolean-algebra

I just found about Boolean algebra and still learning, so be patient ... :)

I'm looking for the following. As far as I understood the problem to find all the possible values of the variables of boolean function is called "satisfiability" problem.

I wan't to do something along the lines of satisfiability.

> The setup is a **function** of 100 to 10_000 variables.
>   The function is simple **XOR** i.e.  **x1 ^ x2 ^ x3 ....**.
>   In addition I have probably half of the variables-values known in advance, so I want to do partial satisfaction.

What is the best way to find a solution ?

I'm currently experimenting with [PyEDA](https://pyeda.readthedocs.io/en/v0.28.0/expr.html), so I can become familiar with boolean algebra in general.
i haven't found a way to do partial-satisfaction yet.
But even if I find one, I want to be able to code the algorithm myself.

After I find a solution to pure XOR-partial-SAT, I would like to explore other formulas too, that is why probably need more general algorithm after I explore the XOR-SAT.

---

Example :

```
>>> ft = 1 ^ a ^ 0 ^ b
>>> list(ft.satisfy_all())
[{a: 0, b: 0}, {a: 1, b: 1}]
```

Comment: So you have just one constraint? That makes it trivial..

Comment: I don't understand the task, probably because of the notation and wording. ```As far as I understood the problem to find all the possible values of the variables of boolean function is called "satisfiability" problem.```. No. The SAT-problem is finding one variable-assignment which evaluates to True (first sentence on wiki's article is saying the same). Finding all possible solutions is usually infeasible, as the number of solutions often grow very very fast (and even counting the number of solutions; called #-SAT / Sharp-SAT is hard in practice).